Formula derivation of Probability of A and B complement given C?
I'm having some trouble with this proof: P(A-B|C) = P(A|C)−P(A∩B|C).
I try incorporating the difference rule, P(A and not B) = P(A) - P(A and B) into the conditional probability formula and intersect it with P(C) in the numerator, but I think I may be wrong, or I don't know how to go about this.
Guidance appreciated, thanks.

You say "proof" but what is it you're trying to show? Or are you instead trying to derive a formula for $P(A - B | C)?$

Sorry, I'm trying to derive the formula


I try incorporating the difference rule, P(A and not B) = P(A) - P(A and B) into the conditional probability formula and intersect it with P(C) in the numerator, but I think I may be wrong, or I don't know how to go about this.

You are not wrong.  Start by applying the definition for conditional probability, and finish by doing the reverse.
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf P(A\smallsetminus B\mid C)&= \mathsf P(A\cap B^\complement\mid C)\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P((A\cap B^\complement)\cap C)}{\mathsf P(C)}\\[2ex]&~~\vdots\\[2ex]&~~\vdots\\[2ex]&~~\vdots\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap C)-\mathsf P((A\cap B)\cap C)}{\mathsf P(C)}\\[2ex]&=\mathsf P(A\mid C)-\mathsf P(A\cap B\mid C) \end{align}$
So just complete the between steps.
